# Load SDK with HTML DOM into nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, jsdom

I am trying to use an SDK that contains `HTML DOM` usage in `NodeJS` (I need the functions of the SDK without actually using a client)

Since the SDK requires `HTML DOM`, then I could not load it using simple require.

So I tried the following way:

```
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom");
const dom = new JSDOM(`<body>
 <script src="./libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  var testVar= 'test';
  var a= jQuery;
</script>
</body>`, {runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable"});
module.exports = dom.window.a;
```

(In the examples I put `JQUERY`, but I use another SDK that I can't put into the question - I am aware that jquery has a npm package, but my SDK does not).

The idea is to export a module that will contain the SDK for `Nodejs`, so I created a simulated dom using `jsdom`.

When I debug, I see that in this line: `module.exports = dom.window.a;` a variable is `undefined`.

But if I change the line: `module.exports = dom.window.testVar;` I do get 'test'.

To test, I created an HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="./libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var a= jQuery;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I run it I do get the `a` variable properly.

So I can not figure out what the problem is with JSDOM.

I would love help, or any other suggestion on how I can load an SDK containing `HTML DOM` into `NodeJS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I was missing at the base was the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Also, it is very important that all the files are **under the same folder**.

I also created HTML that contains the scripts and uploaded it using JSDOM

Here is the fixed code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
const {JSDOM} = require("jsdom");
const options = {
    runScripts: "dangerously",
    resources: "usable"
};
const file = './src/test/index.html';
module.exports = {
    initialize: function (callback) {
        JSDOM.fromFile(file, options).then((dom) => {
            dom.window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                setImmediate(() => {
                    callback({
                        jQuery: dom.window.jQuery
                    });
                });
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
require('../test/').initialize(function (test) {
    if (test.jQuery)
        console.log("Yee");
    else
        console.log("Nope");
});
```

And it printed Yee !!